# HTML / PHP parse a file from memory to src

Tags: php, html

I call a PDF creator class [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org) through AJAX to create a PDF doc which I finally need to display as a preview in a separate browser window. I know that I can use this element:

```
  echo '<embed src="'.$complete_path.'" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="'.MAX_HEIGHT.'px">';
```

But `src` refers to a `filepath` on disk as far as I know. I want to avoid storing a PDF file first on disk while its already created in memory. So my question is if there is a way to parse a given memory buffer to `src` and how to do that ?

Comment: src refers to a path that is *requested from the server*. the server then decides if it just passes through a static file or executes a script that generates a file.

Comment: @Ben Why not just generate the pdf and remove the variable from memory by unsetting it... Parsing it as a blob or whatever to the client you need javascript/AJAX and the likes for that. Seems a bit overkill to me.

Comment: @ Franz Gleichmann - In other words I have to generate a file in any case ?

Comment: @Ben — A PDF is a type of file. If you want to generate a PDF then you have to create a file. There is no requirement to *store* that file on the server in any way. (You probably shouldn't be using Ajax at all to solve this problem)

Comment: serving file using php features is not good, it consumes lots of server resources. why not just have `tmp` folder in public and put it there using `file_put_contents` and give link as `src="http://hostname/tmp/123asd123.pdf"`

Answer (score 2):

If you are calling it via AJAX then the best way to do it is as suggested in comments, create a temporary file in server and return the URL to the client-side because you will need to do two requests, the AJAX request and another from the `embed` tag.

Even though, I think we are forgetting how HTTP works here. You can return a PDF file from a URL. Simply create an `embed` tag and set the `src` attribute to a script that will simply `Output` the contents of your FPDF object. Like this.

```
echo '<embed src="/path/to/script.php" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="'.MAX_HEIGHT.'px">';
```

And in the `/path/to/script.php` file you would put the PDF generation logic.

```
// Create FPDF instance, write content, ...
$FPDF->Output();
```

Comment: First part of your answer is what I am already doing and it works. Second part of your answer is what I want (need) and sounds interesting. I will try it out and come back later. Thanks for the moment.

Comment: I can tell you is the good way :). You will be able to embed your PDF in other pages in your application if needed simply using the resource URL.